After laptop reimage, SpringBoot Language Server init from Eclipse now fails with "ClassNotFoundException: SpringSymbolIndex$2"
I'm using Eclipse 2024-06.
Everything was working reasonably well until last Friday, when my laptop disk died, and I had to get it reimaged.  Most things were recovered, but now when I start Eclipse, I see "Initializing language server ..." and it never completes. I finally enabled the console log for the Language Server, and it shows this:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSymbolIndex' defined in file [C:\Users\dk068x\.p2\pool\plugins\org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.55.1.202406141939\servers\spring-boot-language-server\BOOT-INF\classes\org\springframework\ide\vscode\boot\app\SpringSymbolIndex.class]: org/springframework/ide/vscode/boot/app/SpringSymbolIndex$2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ide/vscode/boot/app/SpringSymbolIndex$2
    at org.springframework.ide.vscode.boot.app.SpringSymbolIndex.afterPropertiesSet(SpringSymbolIndex.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ide.vscode.boot.app.SpringSymbolIndex$2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 32 common frames omitted

I literally didn't change anything in the Eclipse config, this is just what I see when I started Eclipse again after the reimaging and file recovery.
Curiously, I also am having problems with vscode and github copilot that I didn't have before, but I imagine that has to be unrelated.

You might try a fresh workspace: File > Switch Workspace.

No difference. Still continuously failing with the same error.

That doesn't sound good, it seems that your installation is broken. It is strange that not only your Eclipse installation is affected. Make sure that this has not been caused by ransomware encrypting files.

Martin Lippert suggested the same thing (corruption, that is). I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the spring plugins, no help. I guess I'll try a completely new install of 2024-06.

And now, after reinstalling 2024-06 completely, including the plugins from the marketplace that I always install, and then importing my projects from git, I am still getting the same error.

It looks like you used the Eclipse Installer where the same plugins are shared for all Eclipse installations. So probably the same corrupted plugins from C:\Users\dk068x\.p2\pool\plugins are still used.

Ok, interesting. How can I repair ~/.p2? Should I just delete that directory and reinstall again?

Oh. Hah. The answer is provided in an eclipse forum thread I started 8 years ago. I'll proceed with that and see what happens.

Ok, well, I ran the "Analysis Agent" and it didn't find any damaged artifacts. Now what?

I guess I've fixed this. I simply renamed the ~/.p2 directory and reinstalled Eclipse and my plugins.  No more errors. No idea what was wrong.
